# Prevent f.range_field to submit data unless interacted with

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following f.range_field that calls my update method in the controller:

```
= f.range_field :feeling, :in => 1..3, :step => '1'
```

Controller:

```
if @workout.update_attributes(workout_params)
  redirect_to team_user_workouts_path(current_user.team,
    current_user, athlete: params[:athlete])
else
  render(:edit, athlete: params[:athlete])
end
```

With a select_field I would usually `include_blank: 'choose'`, which would make sure that if the select field has not been interacted with - the specific param does not submit. How do I achieve the same with a range field? Right now, it submits even if I don't interact with it.

Comment: Make a hidden field using the attribute name you want to assign. Give the range input a bogus name. Set value using JS when user interacts with input. Done and done.

Comment: Could you try setting the default value to null?

Comment: Ben, how would I set the default value to null? You mean in a migration?